# A local ZeroMQ connection with PAIR sockets is experiencing a port conflict, once one of the sides are run through Docker

Tags: c#, python, .net, docker, zeromq

I was initially running a python script and a .NET program on the same computer, and I decided that ZeroMQ would be the most convenient way of sharing information between these two programs.

This works completely fine if I'm just running them normally, however, I recently tried building a Docker image of the python-script, and whilst it runs completely fine, the .NET program is not able to bind to that socket, as it complains about the address already being in use, which seems like a pretty odd complaint for two sockets that are supposed to communicate with one another.

And just to clarify, running them in the opposite order makes Docker complain about the port already being in use instead.

The relevant python code:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:6008")
```

The relevant C# code:

```
public ClassName(){
        context = ZmqContext.Create();
        sendSocket = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.PAIR);
        sendSocket.Bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:6008");
}
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ADD pythonscriptName.py ./
RUN pip install pyzmq
EXPOSE 6008
CMD [ "python", "./pythonscriptName.py" ]
```

The commands used to create and run the Docker-image:

```
docker build -t pythonscriptName .
docker run -p 6008:6008 -d pythonscriptName
```

Answer (score 2):

### Observation :

A Docker concept creates a sort of **horizon-of-abstraction**, so as to allow a code to be executed in a "Dockerised"-fashion, best without its ever knowing that it is kept and run **inside** such a horizon-of-abstraction.

Being "***under***" such a horizon-of-abstraction is fine for the code under review, yet the "***outer***" world has to somehow maintain such an abstraction to co-exist inside another O/S, where resources get mapped, allocated and used, without coordination with the eco-system hidden "*under*" the horizon-of-abstraction.

This means, what gets simple in a monolythic eco-system, like the loopback O/S-emulated abstract interface, addressed as TCP/IPv4 delivery address **`127.0.0.1`**, is easy for the "outer" O/S ( which knows nothing about anything "inside" any of the horizon-of-abstraction, the less about anything what could be operated "***behind***" its sight and smell, inside those isolated, O/S co-habitant universes ).

ZeroMQ is not a magic wand, if it gets instructed to ask O/S ( the real host one, the virtualised machine one or the one abstracted "behind" the horizon-of-abstraction "inside" a Docker-container ), the respective abstraction of the O/S services simply deliver what has been asked to get -- the real host O/S uses that O/S emulated loopback interface access, the VM-ed O/S will deliver its ( VM-specific ) O/S emulated loopback interface access and no one ought be surprised here, that the emulation "***behind***" the horizon-of-abstraction will do the similar provisioning of a similarly abstracted loopback emulated interface.

Who would expect here, that all those "*very same*" **`127.0.0.1`** addresses ever ought "**meet**" and "**speak**" each to anyone other of these three, principally "**disjunct**"-system **emulation abstractions?**

---

### Solution ?

Best setup ZeroMQ messaging and signalling communication infrastructure nodes against a real, physical device IP-addresses, that can get mapped, cross-connected and communicate "**through**" the horizon-of-abstraction, using Docker's configuration and mapping services, tailor made to your real-host interfaces present + addressing used.

That way the ISO/OSI-Layer3+ services will get properly mediated "**across**" any type of the horizon-of-abstraction, given also a proper respective setup and coordination of host and network addressing took place and security rules enforced on different service-mediating devices are permissive to setup and maintain such types of communications among them.

Best avoid using non-"**translated**" abstractions alike `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, which need not work identically "**through**" these different horizons-of-abstraction ( which was by the way the very reason to introduce the concept of separation "*behind*" the such horizon-of-abstraction, wasn't it? )

---

In case the **`PAIR`** socket "resists" to provide a fair channel "accross" otherwise correctly setup services mediating connections "through" the horizon-of-abstraction, try the **`PUSH/PULL`** test first, to prove the "visibility" works "through" the horizon-of-abstraction.

If **`PUSH/PULL`** channel works, the **`PAIR/PAIR`** may not, as it is documented to be a sort of "experimental" Scalable Formal Communication Archetype pattern, which need not support all common services as other ZeroMQ Archetypes do, as was expressed in ZeroMQ native API since v2.1+

The preventive check with a `PUSH/PULL` setup principally isolates this aspect from any Docker-introduced issues with operations crossing horizon-of-abstraction in either direction, so helpful to pre-test both directions to PASS working "through" before testing the `PAIR/PAIR` setup.

---

Last but not least, one may experience ports remaining used in those cases, where a poor resources-management practice was used and code-execution was thrown into an unhandled exception, while some **`Context()`**-instance(s) still mapped gracefully non-terminated channels onto **`port#`**(s). Such situations may happen, resulting in "hanged"-or-"hanging" other sockets, waiting infinitely for an event, that will never arrive, up until a reboot of such system. So if you experience inaccessible ports after some prior code-crashes, this may be another reason for rejected calls to use such ( not released yet ) `port#`(s).

Welcome to the realms of [distributed-systems](/questions/tagged/distributed-systems), where **`#ASSUME NOTHING`** directive is thus more valid for the whole, distributed-system-wide perspective of system-design best practices.

Comment: Well, it didn't really result in a solution, but i appreciate the answer anyway. I guess i'll just have to manually set up python on every system this is to be used on instead.

Comment: Glad to read about your appreciation, @DavidSpove . StackOverflow users express this by clicking **[ +1 ]** and by clicking the **[ Accept ]** for the best answer provided -- **That's fair, isn't it?** You have also just now mentioned, that "*it didn't really result in a solution*" -- if so, what steps have been tested and PASS-ed as it worked and at which particular step of the problem isolation strategy, posted above, your code / setup has FAIL-ed to work, so as to draw the just commented statement?

Comment: Well, i did click +1, and i assumed "accept" was for when a solution was reached. Secondly, because of your answer, i drew the conclusion that it was simply not worth the effort considering it's pretty non-essential, which is why i wasn't more specific.